# SSIS replace value on write

Tags: ssis, etl, denodo

I've added an integration services project via Visual Studio 2019 and for the data flow task I have the source as an ODBC Source querying Denodo.  I set the access mode to SQL command and pasted this:

```sql
SELECT CAST("Control Number" AS INT4) AS ControlNumber
FROM "location"."bv_SpaceDetail"
```

When I click the Preview button I see the controls numbers as I'd expect them to be.  Then I write that into an OLE DB Destination pointing at my SQL Server 2016 database (build 13.0.5830) and I write that integer value into an column defined as an int.

When the data is written to the table that column is showing up for every record as a 1.  All the other rows that I query/write from Denodo (Obviously I select more than just that one value) populate correctly.  Just this one refuses to come in properly.  I don't know what else to do to try and figure out what is going on.

Comment: Can you include some sample data please, just a record or two showing what's in that field now?  Is it definitely things that can be cast to int4?

Comment: They're all integer values, like 1002845, but unfortunately the Denodo database was created with that as a string value, instead of a numeric value.  In my database I want to fix that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Donodo. Do you have some way to try running the SQL command directly against the database, see what result you get; outside of SSIS?  To try and narrow down where the problem lies?

Comment: The manual https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/6.0/vdp/vql/appendix/syntax_of_condition_functions/type_conversion_functions#cast doesn't specify INT4 as a valid target, could you try Numeric, Float, or Decimal and see if you get the same result?